# Page refreshes upon keypress enter but opens file system on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

```
<a href="" tabindex="0">                                       
    <label for="my_label" class="my_label" name="Upload" data-bind="attr: { for: 'uploadContent' + SubmissionId() }">
        <span>Upload Content</span>
    </label>
    <div class="hidden">
        <input type="button" id="my_label" class="fileupload" data-bind="event: { change: $parent.upload($data, $element, 'zip', false) }, attr: { id: 'uploadContent' + Id() }" accept="application/zip" type="file">
    </div>
</a>
```

This is in a list, so it it's a dropdown. When I tab through the dropdown and press enter on "Upload Content" the page refreshes rather than open the files. It works fine when I click using my mouse.

How can I make the file system open on `keypress` <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: Have you tried adding the tabindex property to the element you want to press enter on?

Answer (score 1):

You can try placing href="javascript:void(0)" instead of href="" as below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="0">                                       
   <label for="my_label" class="my_label" name="Upload" data-bind="attr: {   for: 'uploadContent' + SubmissionId() }">
    <span>Upload Content</span>
</label>
<div class="hidden">
    <input type="button" id="my_label" class="fileupload" data-bind="event: { change: $parent.upload($data, $element, 'zip', false) }, attr: { id: 'uploadContent' + Id() }" accept="application/zip" type="file">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `type="button"` because you have already `type="file"` on the input.

Then you can do something like that.

```js
function handle_enter(ev){
   if (ev.which == 13)
     return document.getElementById('my_label').click();
   
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" tabindex="0" onkeypress="handle_enter(event)">                                       
    <label for="my_label" class="my_label" name="Upload" data-bind="attr: { for: 'uploadContent' + SubmissionId() }">
        <span>Upload Content</span>
    </label>
    <div class="hidden">
        <input id="my_label" class="fileupload" data-bind="event: { change: $parent.upload($data, $element, 'zip', false) }, attr: { id: 'uploadContent' + Id() }" accept="application/zip" type="file">
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the tabindex property to the html element, to make it focusable. This allows for div, label and other non-navigation elements to behave as such. This is a browser feature more than a js one.

Depending on your needs (and the rest of your html tabs), you will want to assign it values -1, 0 or other positive values.

For reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your empty href. It means you can't get native focus with the keyboard without a tabindex attribute, and when it is clicked it will send focus to the top of the page as you've discovered.

So you need to add something useful to the href. The JavaScript suggested by Dhananjaya will work. But a more meaningful value would be the id attribute of the file input, and it won't choke if JavaScript isn't available for any reason.

See if this works better for you:

```
<a href="#my_label">                                       
    <label for="my_label" class="my_label" name="Upload" data-bind="attr: { for: 'uploadContent' + SubmissionId() }">
        <span>Upload Content</span>
    </label>
    <div class="hidden">
        <input id="my_label" class="fileupload" data-bind="event: { change: $parent.upload($data, $element, 'zip', false) }, attr: { id: 'uploadContent' + Id() }" accept="application/zip" type="file">
    </div>
</a>
```